# Running a print event using button click without forms and update mysql database after SUCCESSFUL printing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, printing

I have a very specific requirement in which i am very much confused. I have to include a print button which will print an ID-Card for a user in a user list table. When the user click on print button of a particular user from that table, it has to print a particular ID Card div. Upto this i had coded and can print the ID Card successfully. But after clicking the print button, it will display a Print Confirmation window by default. In that window there are two options as 'Ok' and 'Cancel'. Now my requirement is to update a status value in a mysql db table from 0 to 1 if the user clicks 'OK' button only on that browser's Print Confirmation. If the user clicks 'Cancel' button without printing the document, then nothing has to update in db.

My button code is as given below:

```
<input type="button" name="button" onClick="printDiv('print-row-<?php echo $id; ?>');" value="Print"/>
```

My Print javascript is as given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divName) 
{
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 w=window.open();
 w.document.write(printContents);
 w.print();
 w.close();
 alert('ID Card Printed successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Due to "safety" concerns, you do not have access to that information in a browser. You would have to create a desktop app to get that level of info. At least in a Wndows environment.

Comment: There are other "fail" situations as well. Print to PDF is one that comes to mind. About the only way to implement is to ask the user if it printed OK.

Comment: Print to pdf or print as xps or printing in real printer is ok. Just had to update status in db whether clicked ok or cancel button in that print confirmation window. Not a must requirement to print in printer itself.

Comment: As mentioned, you have no way programmatically to know which button was pressed in the dialog.